# Initialize Object with Pointer Members in a Vector c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, constructor, deep-copy

I would like to be able to call a non-trivial constructor on an object when I use the `push_back()` method. Instead, all I have been able to do is pass a shallow copy of an object to the vector. When using regular c-style arrays, the constructor is automatically called when the array is created, but since vectors are dynamic, the object don't exist yet.

How would I go about adding a new, empty object to a vector without having two pointers point to the same memory address? Do I need a copy constructor or an overloaded assignment operator?

Here is some example code that demonstrates my problem:

```
struct Object
{
    int *Pointer;

    Object()
    {
        Pointer = new int;
        *Pointer = 42;
    }

    ~Object()
    {
        delete Pointer;
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector <Object> *Array;
    Array = new std::vector <Object>;

    // Attempt 1
    Array->push_back(Object());

    // Attempt 2
    {
        Object LocalInstance;
        Array->push_back(LocalInstance);
    }

    // Error here because the destructor has already been called for 
    // LocalInstance and for Object()
    delete Array;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don’t use pointers here. It’s unnecessary, and makes the code less efficient and more complicated.

Comment: This is a simplification of the actual code, in order to make the problem easier to see / debug. The actual code must have these pointers.

Comment: Even if you really need a pointer, you should prefer smart pointers in STL containers such as [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) or [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: @dbank I think you mean [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Comment: @Caleth Hmm... I'm not sure what was going through my mind back when I made that comment, but yes, I agree that unique_ptr's would be my default choice for smart pointers unless there was an actual need for shared ownership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@KonradRudolph is correct - there is no reason for `Array` to be a pointer here and it just obfuscates the code.

The reason your code crashes is because LocationInstance is passed to `push_back` but your `Object` doesn't have a proper copy constructor, so only a shallow copy of the `Pointer` member is copied. When the LocalInstance goes out of scope, that object deletes its `Pointer` but the copy in the container has the same `Pointer`, which results in deleting freed memory when the container is cleaned up.

Please check out the [Rule-of-Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11) (was Rule-of-Three before C++11).

In terms of construction objects as you add them to the container, are you using C++11? If so, you can `emplace_back` and construct the object in the container as it is added - is that what you're looking to do?

This trivial example only gives me a warning with clang:

```
struct A
{
    A(int a) : member_m(a)
    {}

    int &member_m;
};
int main() {
    A a(1);
}
```

gives me:

```
~/ClionProjects/so_reference_to_temporary $ clang++ -o test main.cpp
main.cpp:8:25: warning: binding reference member 'member_m' to stack allocated
      parameter 'a' [-Wdangling-field]
    A(int a) : member_m(a)
                        ^
main.cpp:13:10: note: reference member declared here
    int &member_m;
         ^
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: I used a pointer for the array of objects because without it an error does not get thrown (at least not for me). What would happen is the memory would be deallocated, but the pointer member of the object in the aray would point to an invalid memory address. I dynamically allocated the array in order to force the compiler to generate an error when the destructor was called twice.

Comment: That would just be "luck" - deleting freed memory is undefined behavior. As with many memory bugs, sometimes, when you're lucky, it will crash. Sometimes it will just silently work correctly until it doesn't. Tools like valgrind are very helpful for checking ones code for such issues.

Comment: You were right, all I needed was a copy constructor. For some reason it didn't work the first time, but now it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// constructors examples 

class myClass 
{
    private:
        int* data;
    public:
        //constructor 
        myClass(int value)
        {
            data = new int ;
            *data = value ;

        } 

        //copy constructor 
        myClass (const myClass& other)
            :myClass(*other.data)
        {
                
        }

        //move constructor 
        myClass (myClass&& other)
            :data(other.data)
        {
            other.data = nullptr ;
             
        }

        //destructor 
        ~myClass ()
        {
            delete data ;
            
        }
        //copy assignment 

        myClass& operator=(myClass other)
        {
            std::swap (data, other.data);   
            return *this ;
        }

};

int main ()
{
    myClass M1(5);
    myClass M2=M1;
    myClass M3(M2);
    M1 = M3;
    myClass M4(std::move(M1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does that piece of code answer OP's question? Please edit and explain.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.